# How can I say my Discord bot doesn't react to direct messages, only in a server chat channel?

Tags: javascript, discord

```
client.on('message', function(message) { // COMMAND CLEAR [+]
    if (message.content.startsWith('/dm ') && message.mentions.users.size){
      message.send("ERROR")
    } 
    if (message.content == ".c") {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            message.channel.fetchMessages(1000)
               .then(function(list){
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(list);
                }, function(err){message.channel.send()})                 
        }
    }

}); // COMMAND CLEAR [-]
```

I just want the bot to only react to this command on Discord server channels, and not in direct messages.

Answer (score 0):

Per the discord.js documentation, the property [`.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) exists on [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), which is of type `TextChannel | DMChannel | GroupDMChannel`.

So the best way to check the origin of a message is to check the `instanceof` the channel property:

```
client.on("message", message => {
   if (message instanceof TextChannel) {
      // Was posted in a text channel, and not a DM
   }
})
```

Note: you will need to import `TextChannel` from the module. Assuming you're using TypeScript (I've only ever used discord.js with typescript) it looks like this:

```js
import { TextChannel } from "discord.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the bot to ignore a message if its a dm

```
client.on("message", msg => {

    if (msg.type == "dm") {
        return;
    }
```

If you want to reply with a message you can do this:

```
client.on("message", msg => {

    if (msg.type == "dm") {
        msg.channel.send(`Sorry ${msg.author.username}, you can't do this`)
    }
```